# how extract data inputted using form and display it using php in table

Tags: php, html, webforms, xhtml

I am not sure how to go about doing this, but I have an assignment tomorrow and i'm new in php i have to put in the html part  a text box and check bob and radio button and drop down list and then take data from user and then extract data in php and display it in table also using php . Any one can helps me please

Answer (score 0):

file.html

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br>From<br>
<input type="radio" name="from" value="us">US<br>
<input type="radio" name="from" value="else">Else<br>
<select name="car">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat" selected>Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

file.php

```
   <?php
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   //this takes the data from input
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $car = $_POST['car'];
    echo "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>From</td><td>Car</td></tr>
    <tr><td>".$name."</td><td>".$from."</td><td>".$car."</td></tr></table>";`
    ?>
```

This will return a table with the inserted values.

Comment: how can i do the same with a drop down list ?

Comment: @bessan al bessani, this type of drop-down list? with select and option?